# How to set a Where clause on the top (parent) level in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, where-clause, date-range

I'm relatively new to PostgreSQL.

My issue is that I have apartments with their reservations and I need select those are available (don't have reservations) for a given range.

Reservations table has fields apartmentId (which references Apartments table), userId and datesReserved which is `tstzrange`.

For these purposes I'm doing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM apartments 
JOIN appointments ON appointments.aparmentId = apartments.id 
WHERE NOT(datesreserved && '[2020-12-15T15:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-17T16:00:00.000Z)');
```

But instead I'm getting filtered appointments - those that do not contain the value `[2020-12-15T15:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-17T16:00:00.000Z)`.

As far as I researched there are top-level where and inner-level, and as far as I understand this query should give me top-level results - those apartments that **do not contain the provided range**.

Am I understanding correctly in this case?

Comment: You mean`contains` rather than `overlaps`? To save some time: could you add a data sample and the exact expected result?

Comment: Hi @JimJones! I need overlaps which will be more accurate rather than contain. Example: Apartment (id: 1, address: ‘5th ave’), Apartment(id: 2, address: ‘7th ave’), Appointment (id: 1, apartmentId: 1, datesReserved: ‘[2020-12-15T14:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-20T12:00:00.000Z)’), Appointment (id: 2, apartmentId: 1, datesReserved: ‘[2021-12-15T14:00:00.000Z, 2021-12-20T12:00:00.000Z)’) and Appointment(id: 3, apartmentId: 2, datesReserved: ‘[2020-12-15T14:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-20T12:00:00.000Z)’). THUS, when I specify Where as NOT(datesReserved && ‘[2020-12-15T14:00:00.000Z, …) and I expect to get nothing

Comment: Since both apartments overlap and thus they are unavailable. But what I’m getting is just an apartment with id = 1 and with appointments.id = 2. That means that postgres filters appointments and gives those that dont overlap with the specified value. But I need to filter apartments, not appointments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help] Clarify via edits not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need NOT EXISTS here. As it is, you don't have a "top level", the tables are peers.

```
SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from appointments WHERE appointments.aparmentId = apartments.id and datesreserved && '[2020-12-15T15:00:00.000Z, 2020-12-17T16:00:00.000Z)'
);
```